# Uploading project to Google Cloud repository in Android Studio fails

Tags: git, google-app-engine, android-studio

Trying to use Google cloud debugger. I need to upload the source to Google Cloud repository. I followed the instructions here https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/vcs

When I choose "VCS > Import into Version Control > Upload Project to Google Cloud > Upload" it gives this message

[image]

How can I upload source to google cloud so I can get started with cloud debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/), you can follow [those instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-vcs-specific-settings.html) first, before getting the repo:

> To configure vcs-specific settings, follow these general steps
>
> - Open the **[Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-settings.html)** dialog box and then click Version Control.
> - Click a page that corresponds to the VCS to be configured.
> - Set up options as required. For detailed information, see VCS-specific pages of the Version Control settings.